# TransformException when adding Google Places library along with multi dex support

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Placed library in my app. 
After adding the play services dependency, I got the error saying I need to use multi dex as number of method references was more than 65536.

Then I followed the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) to add multi dex support and then I started getting this error (transformexception).

From what I understood, this is because multiple dependencies have some classes in common, which are required to be excluded.

I did some research on SO and excluded a few already. But still, I get the same error, but this time just for a new class name.

Error says:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.class

This is my module level gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.exampleapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:3.8.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile ('com.android.support:design:24.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.1.2'
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/Grover-c13/PokeGOAPI-Java/issues/354), you can get rid of the **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'** by downloading the newest version of API.

You can also try enabling multidex and use the packaging options listed in this [related issue](https://github.com/Grover-c13/PokeGOAPI-Java/issues/362).

```
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.moshi/moshi/pom.properties'
exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.moshi/moshi/pom.xml'

    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.properties'

    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.xml'

    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.annimon/stream/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.annimon/stream/pom.xml'

    exclude 'META-INF/maven/net.iharder/base64/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/net.iharder/base64/pom.properties'

    pickFirst 'gpsoauth.properties'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/any.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/field_mask.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/plugin.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/api.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/descriptor.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/wrappers.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/type.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/struct.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/timestamp.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/source_context.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/duration.proto'
    pickFirst 'google/protobuf/empty.proto'

}
```

Hope this helps!